# Android Java Firebase Credential Initialization

Tags: android, firebase

I want to link an Android App to Firebase to use Firestore database, Analytics, and crashlytics.  I am attempting to use `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` to set the credentials.

Setting the credentials directly in the code allows for the possibility of obfuscating the credentials instead of leaving them in google-services.json.

I found the following article on medium which addresses this: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/secure-your-firebases-google-services-json-file-in-android-16680f8e5fb4

However, trying to implement calling `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` results in the app crashing with no apparent errors or exceptions in logcat. I'm doing the following (credentials X'ed out for obvious reasons)

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setApplicationId( "XXXXXXXXX")
    .setGcmSenderId("XXXXXXXXX")
    .setApiKey("XXXXXXXXX")
    .setStorageBucket("XXXXXXXXX")
    .setProjectId("XXXXXXXXX")
    .build());
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

- The value in `setApplicationId()` is set to the mobilesdk_app_id in google-services.json
- The value in `setGcmSenderId()` is set to the project_number in google-services.json
- The value in `setApiKey()` is set to the current_key inside the api_key object in google-services.json
- The value in `setStorageBucket()` is set to the storage_bucket in google-services.json
- The value in `setProjectId()` is set to project_id in google-services.json.

Note that the medium article includes one more function call `.setDatabaseUrl()`. This was a problem as there is apparent database URL in google-services.json file, I've been told I can get the database URL from the Realtime Database section of the Firebase console, but I'm not using the realtime database, I'm using Firestore database, so I don't include it.

With the call to `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` the app crashes, commenting out the call and the app runs.

I also tried `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);` as I was told that that would initialize using the google-services.json file, it doesn't crash but the data still goes to the old Firebase project.

I also tried storing the return value of the `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` call in a FirebaseApp variable and passing it to the `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(app)` call, but it still crashes with no errors in logcat.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When an app crashes, it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat. Please find those, and add them to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.

Comment: Hello,  Thank you for responding to my question, please see the fourth paragraph, one of the issue that mystifies me is the absence of any error messages in logcat.